# How can I reinstall OEM windows 10 after replacing the hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, license

I bought a new laptop, but it came with too little hard drive space. I've got a big SSD that I'd like to install, but my computer didn't come with a CD to reinstall Windows (it came with 7, but I upgraded to 10).

**What do I need to do in order to get Windows 10 installed on a computer after I change the hard drive?**

Comment: You download the appropriate version of the [.ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) then install Windows 10.  You can either place the .ISO on a USB flash device or on an optical disk.  How you do that is a separate question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone your disk, this way you won't need to reinstall everything.
There are several free tools that you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a system recovery USB drive and reinstall from that. Open control panel, find Recovery, and then select Create Recovery drive and follow the directions. Its pretty simple.

**Do this even if you don't upgrade the drive...its your easiest way of reinstalling Windows without having to send the laptop back under warranty!!** Sadly, I learned this the hard way.